# mysql combining records from one table

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a single table that uses test# as the primary key. Here is what that table looks like:

```
Test# Name VerbalScore readingScore    Notes
  1   Bobby  92                       Good job
  2   Bobby                  40       You Suck Bobby
```

The problem is I want to view and be able to see when there are multiple verbal scores for the same Name (so be able to see if the person took the same test more than once).

I want to have some kind of select statement to get this result from the above table:

```
1   Bobby   92   40   Good job, You Suck Bobby
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure I understand what you mean by "see when there are multiple verbal scores" but with mysql 5+, try

```
SELECT
   Name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(VerbalScore),
   GROUP_CONCAT(readingScore),
   GROUP_CONCAT(Notes)
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   Name;
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is a mysql specific grouping function.